# Why use "what is ... to/by me" rather than "my ... thing"?

Tags: grammar, nuance

I noticed that in English we say, "My favorite thing", and it's okay, but we don't say, "My well-liked thing".  Why is this?  Why use, "What is well-liked by me ..."?

Answer (score 1):

In English (apart from some regional dialects), *"my"* is a definite relative pronoun. If you say *"my nice shirt",* you are either implying that you only have one nice shirt, or you are referring to a nice shirt that was already mentioned in the conversation. So *"my"* works with *"favorite"*, because you can only have one favorite thing, but not with *"well-liked"*, as there are probably several things that you like a lot. You would generally say *"one of my well-liked things"*.

There's another reason, which is that *"well-liked"* is a relatively cumbersome adjective, and people are much more likely to use an expression like *"one of my treasured things"* than *"one of my well-liked things"*. (Google does return a few hits for *"one of my well-liked things"*, but none for *"my well-liked thing"*.)

Comment: Actually, "one of my well-liked things" also sounds things.  For example, "one of my important things".

Comment: I don't agree that "my" implies there is only one of an object. "Let me get my coat" means "Let me get *a* coat [that is mine]".

Comment: @MrHen: Even if you have more than one coat, *"my"* in *"my coat"* is still a definite relative pronoun.  If you say *"let me get my coat"* you are talking about a specific one of them. There's a difference between *"Can I borrow a coat"* and *"Can I borrow your coat."*

Comment: "My nice shirt" still wouldn't imply "that you only have one nice shirt". It only implies that you are *talking about* one nice shirt. This "talking about" doesn't need a previous mention in the conversation, which is what you have written here.

Comment: @MrHen Don't you think that the speaker's referencing a single coat (even-if in the context of an indeterminable amount of other coats)?  So, if you say "`my adj. n.`", then you're isolating the single `n.` that is `adj.`?  For example, `"my blue coat" = "my only blue coat"` (whether or not other coats are present).  As per "`my nice shirt`", there would be something specific about that shirt such that the listener has it in his or her register.  The language should still isolate, or at least attempt to isolate, a single item.  The plural form being '`one of my ~`'.

Comment: @PeterShor I'm specifically trying to confirm that favorite/favourite (if you hate French) is a superlative and source that info.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: No, "my" does not imply it is your only one. It *can* in certain circumstances but it is not built into the word. The example I've used here should illustrate that: "Let me get my coat" means "Let me get a coat that is mine" not "I have only one coat; let me get it."

Comment: @Wolfpack: What more do you want to know about favorite that the [dictionary definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/favourite), *"preferred to all others of the same kind",* doesn't tell you?

Comment: @Peter of course, people sometimes don't agree with dictionaries because they have often wrong info or missing info. Neologisms are a good example of how human lexis is ahead of machine lexis. Dictionaries can't encompass the sheer mass of meanings we have, now, for words. Not only that, but humans can describe things to meet the learner's need. For example, dictionaries are sparse of exclusion. My coworkers do not agree with the dictionary, much to my frustration, so I sought this, another form of confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

"well-liked" usually refers to the opinions of *others*:

> [well-liked](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/well-liked) — liked by many people; popular

You can say "this is my well-liked shirt" but it means "this is my shirt that is liked by may people" or "this is my popular shirt."

"favorite", on the other hand, usually refers to *your* opinion of your shirt. The confusion is understandable since the dictionary definition of "favorite" doesn't note this connotation:

> [favorite](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/favorite?s=t) — regarded with particular favor or preference

The reason is because "my" modifies "favorite" more than it modifies "thing". For instance:

> This soda is my favorite drink.
>
> This soda is my well-liked drink.

The first example just says this drink is your favorite. There is an *implied* ownership but it can also be a generic statement.

The second example implies that the *soda* is yours. Most likely, this is a soda of your own making and other people like it.

Comment: Right, well I'm thinking: "It's my most-liked".  Some of the instructors at my school don't believe that "favorite" is a superlative.  Isn't that silly?  Likest just sounds strange....

Comment: My "favorite" would be a superlative unless you used "*a* favorite". "Most well-liked" would be fine; "most liked" would also make sense.

Answer (score 0):

"Favorite" generally defaults to singular, unless stated otherwise, and is in any case a fairly small set.

"Well-liked" unavoidably applies to a huge number of things... which both means it's plural, and makes it not useful in indicating a subset. So I can't think of a situation where I would say either "my well-liked things" or "what is well-liked by me"; I'd say "some of the things I like", or "the things I like" if I really intend to include all of them, or perhaps "what I like (or like most) about this is..." if I'm about to enumerate the reasons.